# Flutter, url_launcher

Tags: flutter, dart

Please help with url_launcher. Added everything to pubspec.yaml. I'm still just learning and everything is much clearer with an example. What is wrong with me here? I need to put a link to the button on the button.

```
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            const url = 'https://google.com';
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              fixedSize: const Size(350, 50),
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
          child: Text(
            "Common Bond booklet",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

To open link when button is pressed you can do something like this (inside button widget):

```
onPressed: () {
  launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://example.com'));
},
```

It is always good practice to make sure that URL is valid before launchUrl invocation, something like:

```
onPressed: () {
  final uri = Uri.tryParse('some link here');
  if (uri != null) {
    launchUrl(uri);
  }
},
```

In common, url_launcher is accepting object of dart Uri class as a parameter: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html.

So in case of ElevatedButton it can look like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    final uri = Uri.tryParse('<some url here>');
    if (uri != null) {
      launchUrl(uri);
    }
  },
  child: const Text('<some text button here>'),
),
```

Just remember to import url_launcher:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```